# Django microblog showing a logged in user only his posts

Tags: django, post, blogs

I have a miniblog application, with a class named New (referring to a new post), having a foreign key to an user(who has posted the entry).
above I have a method that displays all the posts from all the users.

I'd like to show to the logged in user only his posts.

How can I do it?

```
def paginate(request):
  paginator = New.objects.all()
  return render_to_response('news/newform.html', {
    'object_list': paginator,

    }, 
    context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: New may be a valid class name, but I would strongly advise you to rename it. It's very easy to get confused with other linguistic constructs.

Comment: yes, you're perfectly right, i was thinking about it, it should be done !:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if request.user.is_authenticated():
   paginator = New.objects.filter(user=request.user)
```

(If you haven't already, it's worth checking out the [Django Book](http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/))